# WSGI application 'Uploading.wsgi.application' could not be loaded

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

while i am run my project after add this middleware

`social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware`

i got this error

```
   raise ImproperlyConfigured(django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'Uploading.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Comment: and the rest of the code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

probably not installed middleware
try:

pip install whitenoise